# Why am I getting a "/ by zero" error in this program?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Write a description of class TicTacToe here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe
{
    public static void main(){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int state = 0, turn = 1, choice, drawcheck=0;
        
        for(int end=0; end==0; end=end){
            System.out.println("\u000c");
            for(int i =1; i<10; i++){
                if(state%(3^i)==0){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                else if(state%(3^i)==1){
                    System.out.print("X");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("O");
                }
                if(i%(3^i)==0){
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("Enter State (max 59048)");
            state=s.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game, but for some reason this gets a Divide by Zero error? I am an absolute coding noob, can someone help? (I know this isn't the game, I was trying to isolate the parts, this one gets the error)

Comment: A few things of note: your loop is unusual, you never update `end`. The ^ operator is not the "power of" function. That's `Math.pow()` in java, ^ is the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: Your sample code contains unused variables. It's also not obvious what you expect from `System.in` and what you want to write to `System.out`. It would help to provide sample input, desired output, and actual output.

Comment: I think what you're looking for with the ^ (xor) operator is to check if something is divisible by three. That code is ``(i % 3) == 0``.

Answer (score 8):

I have a feeling you are trying to use modulo 3 to the power of i.

However `^` sign means XOR, not power, so it happens, that you get 3 % 0 - which is basically zero division.

If you want to the power i th power of 3 you need `Math.pow(3, i)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi seems you have mistaken the ^ operator it is XOR

so when i = 3 in binary 11

> 3^i = 11 XOR 11 => 0

XOR is binary operator and compares bits at i-th index and returns 1 if only one bit at i-th index is 1. This means when you xor same numbers you get 0

[Update] Fixed decimal representation of 3 :p

Comment: Your on the right track. However decimal 3 is binary 11 - binary 101 is decimal 5